# How to use rails server and bot with procfile and foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, foreman, procfile

I am trying to run my `rails server` and `slackbot` in two processes using `Procfile` and `gem 'foreman'`.

But when I use `foreman start` the bot is only running the server is not starting up. I tried removing the line bot and tried to run web only but in that case, also my server is not starting up it just shows `started with pid 1502`. But when I start it from another terminal with `rails s` it starts up with no problem. I have googled a lot and can't seem to find out a solution for this. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

This is my Procfile :

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
bot: rails runner -e development slackbot/slack.rb
```

Comment: What is the foreman command you are running?

Comment: @Kris ```foreman start```

Comment: What happens when you point a browser at `localhost:3000` (or whatever the port is)?

Comment: It returns an error ```Could not get any response from server``` when i try to fire an api from postman.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right port? Try hardcoding it in the Procfile.

Comment: I tried ```bundle exec rails server -p 3000``` but still the same.

Comment: @Kris Thanks hardcoding -p 3000 worked and i would like to know when i push it to production if removing -p 3000 will work ?

Comment: Removing `-p 3000` will mean the server starts on the default port, for webrick it is 3000, but for other servers it is different. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you perhaps need to specify the port, either set the environment var `PORT`:

```
export PORT=3000
foreman start
```

or hardcode the port in `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p 3000
```

or remove the `-p` option, in which case the default port will be used:

```
web: bundle exec rails server
```

Comment: When i hardcode port 3000 it works like a charm in development but when i push it on to heroku it doesn't start. Does heroku use a different port to run the application ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. That is a different question.

Comment: I just used ```-p $PORT``` and heroku picks up the port they want all fine now thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing Heroku sets the PORT env var.

Comment: Yes it does i was just trying to fix an issue before it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following config:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p 3000
bot: rails runner -e development slackbot/slack.rb
```

Then run `foreman start -f Procfile` (or what file name you added)

Access: http://localhost:3000

Usually, I like using screen command to open the foreman process in the background, but this is not required here... it looks like: `screen foreman start -f Procfile` then I can just click ctrl + A + D to detach and the processes run in the background. This is useful for SSH connections e.g., EC2 instances.

Comment: My server is running when i hardcode 3000 but the application is not working in heroku. I guess heroku uses a different port for hosting applications do you know which port is it ?